# How to set multiple properties using Lambda in Action delegate

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

This is probably simple, but I can't figure out how to set multiple properties in a single statement.

**LCCorsOptions.cs**:

```
public class LCCorsOptions
{
    public int AppId { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; } = "1.0";
}
```

This is what I got so far:

```
app.UseLCCors(o => o.Version = "1.0");
```

I've tried multiple approaches, but with no luck

Comment: I'm setting the value, not checking if they equal something

Comment: try `{o.Version = "1.0"; o.AppId = 1;}`

Comment: Why you don't use a plain `foreach` loop? The right approach is: `foreach(var o in app.UseLCCors) o.Version="1.0";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is about lambda syntax, the part on the right is a normal method body that you may shorten when it is 1 expression or 1 statement. Otherwise, use full `{ }`and `;`

```
app.UseLCCors(o => {o.Version = "1.0"; o.AppId = 2; });
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're using an extension method that's something like this:

```
  public static void UseLCCors(this List<LCCorsOptions> list, Action<LCCorsOptions> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            action(item);
        }
    }
```

If so try to put some braces after the lambda sign like this:

```
app.UseLCCors(x => { x.Version = "1"; x.AppId = 1; });
```

Is this what you've been looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to give a `LCCorsOptions` in the initialization of your app. Can't you do something like this:

```
app.UseLCCors(new LCCorsOptions{Version = "1.0", AppId = 2});
```

Comment: I ended up with this: app.UseLCCors(o => { o.AppId = 1; o.Version = "1.0"; });